# Как объединить некоторые записи?

Tags: yii2, yii, php, mysql

При выборке из бд выходит, что на 1 запись одной таблицы приходится 1-n записей из другой.

```
author | id | name
         1    Василий
         2    Петров
         3    Николаев

books  | id | title
         1    матан
         2    химия

book_author   id_book  |  id_author
                 1           1
                 1           3
                 2           2
```

При выборке выходит следующий объект:

```
foreach($model as $row)
{
    echo $row['title_ru']." -- ".$row['fio_ru']."<br>";  
}
```

> 1. матан => Василий
> 2. матан => Николаев
> 3. химия => Петров

Вопрос, как сделать выборку, чтобы было:

```
 1. матан => [Василий,Петров]
 2. химия => [петров]
```

Я потом хочу оформить как

```
 1.  матан  | Василий,Николаев 
 2.  химия  | Петров
```

Код выборки данных:

```
$model = Tutorials::findBySql('SELECT title_ru,fio_ru
           FROM Tutorials AS t
            INNER JOIN author_tutorial as at ON t.id = at.id_tutorial
             INNER JOIN Lectors as l ON l.id = at.id_author')->asArray()->all();
```

Comment: Вы что, руками из базы данные достаете?

Comment: Не понимаю, из-за чего такой вывод?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, кодом выборки, может это как-то поможет

Comment: @Юра Сучко из того, что в с массивами работаете. И такой подход никогда не даст вам нужную вложенность за один запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через ActiveRecord, которая специально создана, чтобы не писать вручную джойны (писалось с документации, где-то могут быть косяки):

```
namespace app\models;
class Author
{
    ...
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getBooks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::className(), ['id' => 'id_book'])->viaTable('author_book_relationship', ['id_author' => 'id']);
    }
    ...
}

namespace app\models;
class Book
{
    ...
    public function getAuthors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Author::className(), ['id' => 'id_author'])->viaTable('author_book_relationship', ['id_book' => 'id']);
    }
    ...
}
```

...

```
foreach (Book::findAll() as $book) {
    echo sprintf(
        '%s | %s',
        $book->title,
        implode(', ', $book->getAuthors())
    );
}
```

Comment: Напрочь отказывается искать авторов, ф-я $book->getAuthors(), из-за нее ошибка, т.к. она не находит авторов и передает пустой аргумент.

Comment: Разные варианты пробовал, id берет, а далее по этому id должно список авторов найти, но, увы, не находит.

Comment: @Юра Сучко, если вы просто скопировали пример, то вам надо заменить название таблицы на настоящее и убедиться, что поля проставлены правильно.

Comment: Я весь вечер сижу, разные варианты пробовал,если я бы не догадался заменить поля с примера, то мне даже не стоило бы тут что либо было делать), а идти другим делом заниматься. 
Даже примеры с интернета брал, под них делал таблицы, модели, всё тщётно...